# How can I parse multiple entire lines of text into octave 'matrix'

Tags: octave

I want to import a lot of data from multiple files from multiple sub files. Luckily the data is consistent in its output:

```
Subpro1/data apples 1 
Subpro1/data oranges 1 
Subpro1/data banana 1
```

then

```
Subpro2/data apples 1 
Subpro2/data oranges 1 
Subpro2/data banana 1
```

I want to have a a `datafilename` array that holds the file names for each set of data I need to read. Then I can extract and store the data in a more local file, process it and eventually compare 'sub1_apples' to 'sub2_apples'

I have tried

```
fid = fopen ("DataFileNames.txt");
DataFileNames = fgets (fid)
fclose (fid);
```

But this only gives me the first line of 7.

`DataFileNames = dlmread('DataFileNames.txt')` gives me a `7x3` array but only  `0   0   1` in each line as it reads the name breaks as delimiters and I cant change the file names.

`DataFileNames = textread("DataFileNames.txt", '%s')` 
has all the correct information but still the delimiters split it across multiple lines

```
data
apples
1
data
oranges
1 
...
```

Is there a `%`? that I am missing, if so what is it?

I want the output to be:

```
data apples 1 
data oranges 1 
data banana 1
```

With spaces, underscores and everything included so that I can then use this to access the data file.

Answer (score 2):

You can read all lines of the file to a cell array like this:

```
str = fileread("DataFileNames.txt");
DataFileNames = regexp(str, '\r\n|\r|\n', 'split');
```

Output:

```
DataFileNames =
{
  [1,1] = data apples 1
  [1,2] = data oranges 1
  [1,3] = data banana 1
}
```

In the first option you tried, using `fgets` you are reading just one line. Also, its better to use `fgetl` to remove the line end. To read line by line (which is longer) you need to do:

```
DataFileNames = {};
fid = fopen ("DataFileNames.txt");
line = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(line)
    if ~isempty(line)
        DataFileNames = [DataFileNames line];
    endif
    line = fgetl(fid);
endwhile
fclose (fid);
```

The second option you tried, using `dlmread` is not good because it is intended for reading numeric data to a matrix.

The third option you tried with `textread`, is not so good because it treats all white spaces (spaces, line-ends, ...) equally

Comment: Excellent, that worked great thank you.  
Do you know where i can read a breakdown of how `regexp(str, '\r\n|\r|\n', 'split');` works?

Comment: @Ben: It searches for end-lines (`\r\n` or `\r` or `\n`) in a string using **regular expression** and splits the string where end-lines are found. See [Octave regexp documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/regexp.html), [MATLAB regexp documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)